# Password is not encoding in Grails 2.2.4

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying to reset the user's password. But password is not encoding

```
String salt = saltSource instanceof NullSaltSource ? null : params.username
String userPass = springSecurityUiService.encodePassword(params.password, salt)
println(userPass)  // here printing provided(123456) password directly

/* Update password */
User.executeUpdate("Update User b set b.password = " + springSecurityUiService.encodePassword(params.password, salt) + " WHERE b.personId=" + params.person.id)

redirect(controller: 'person', action: 'index')
```

Comment: Where is your `saltSource` defined? And how it is getting initialized?

Comment: And why do you have an `instanceof` check if this is your own code?

Comment: Also, _never_ concatenate strings like that for HQL or SQL - google "SQL injection". Use `?` placeholders (for SQL or HQL) or named args (when using HQL)